# Получить видео VKontakte Api

Tags: вконтакте, ios, vkontakte-api, видео

Привет всем) такая проблемка - не могу получить ссылку на видео.  Есть `access_key, vid, owner_id`. Все это я получаю из `newsfeed`. Причем, на странице документации ВК, если в поле для проверки запроса вписать просто `owner_id`, то без проблем выдает весь список видеозаписей данного пользователя/группы, но если установить `videos`, то приходит ответ типа

```
response: {
count: 1,
items: []
}
```

т.е., `items` - пустой. Причем я пробовал и с `access_key` и без него. 
Кто такое уже делал, подскажите, что у меня не так?

Comment: В данный момент ссылки на видео не выдаются, даже без "User-Agent"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все, разобрался. В русской версии документации API неполное описание. Пользуйтесь английской версией!

Answer (score 2):

> Обычно ВК не отдает прямой ссылки на видео

Это потому-что используете заголовок запроса "User-Agent", если он пуст то тогда и будут прямые ссылки в files.
Сделайте запрос типа:

https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?videos=-53956136_169543800&access_token=%access_token%

с пустым заголовком "User-Agent", выйдет:

```
{
    'response' : [1, {
            'duration' : 1452,
            'vid' : 169543800,
            'views' : 4790,
            'owner_id' : -53956136,
            'player' : 'https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-53956136&id=169543800&hash=06da65ec2f1a6d00',
            'date' : 1408830421,
            'link' : 'video-53956136_169543800',
            'files' : {
                'mp4_240' : 'https://cs543208.vk.me/u222975331/videos/fd8d6c3d4d.240.mp4?extra=d1xg726trlMQIwAZ4X8NTUJRI2kk-uw9TJ66bWZtq_odwiDxYverCALb8PNb_z-zjbPhvX07ftxnZRXZ-li8XiFKJZ_oEJnbrPVPqLrKUiFM9J1FfYFEEm3c5SfRXRDSSU29k7QTkS_7uTxg',
                'mp4_720' : 'https://cs543208.vk.me/u222975331/videos/fd8d6c3d4d.720.mp4?extra=d1xg726trlMQIwAZ4X8NTUJRI2kk-uw9TJ66bWZtq_odwiDxYverCALb8PNb_z-zjbPhvX07ftxnZRXZ-li8XiFKJZ_oEJnbrPVPqLrKUiFM9J1FfYFEEm3c5SfRXRDSSU29k7QTkS_7uTxg',
                'mp4_360' : 'https://cs543208.vk.me/u222975331/videos/fd8d6c3d4d.360.mp4?extra=d1xg726trlMQIwAZ4X8NTUJRI2kk-uw9TJ66bWZtq_odwiDxYverCALb8PNb_z-zjbPhvX07ftxnZRXZ-li8XiFKJZ_oEJnbrPVPqLrKUiFM9J1FfYFEEm3c5SfRXRDSSU29k7QTkS_7uTxg',
                'mp4_480' : 'https://cs543208.vk.me/u222975331/videos/fd8d6c3d4d.480.mp4?extra=d1xg726trlMQIwAZ4X8NTUJRI2kk-uw9TJ66bWZtq_odwiDxYverCALb8PNb_z-zjbPhvX07ftxnZRXZ-li8XiFKJZ_oEJnbrPVPqLrKUiFM9J1FfYFEEm3c5SfRXRDSSU29k7QTkS_7uTxg'
            },
            'description' : 'Видео предоставлено группой [club53956136|AniZUR Аниме на любой вкус]<br><br>Следующая серия: http://vk.com/video-53956136_169543833',
            'comments' : 5,
            'title' : 'Hunter x Hunter Remake / Хантер x Хантер - 2 сезон 66 серия [Озвучка: Ancord]',
            'image' : 'http://cs543208.vk.me/u222975331/video/m_1a4f8d0d.jpg',
            'image_medium' : 'http://cs543208.vk.me/u222975331/video/l_7bbad3fc.jpg'
        }
    ]
}
```

Если нужен постоянный access_token(**может быть опасно**) вот:

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3087106&scope=wall,offline&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token

*!Обновлено*

Новый ВК API теперь требует новый обязательный параметр: версию API: v=5.73(Актуальная на данный момент).
И полная ссылка будет выглядеть примерно так:

https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?videos=-53956136_169543800&access_token=%access_token%&v=5.73

Comment: почему thumbnail такого плохого качества, мне нужен минимум 800x450 (у вк такой есть)

Comment: @userr Ну тут зависит от того **есть ли** на сервере vk сгенерированный thumbnail конкретно к искомому видео, вот в `-89114073_171719980` есть photo_800, ссылка используя API: https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?videos=-89114073_171719980&access_token=%access_token%&v=5.73

Answer (score 2):

> Это потому-что используете заголовок запроса "User-Agent", если он пуст то тогда и будут прямые ссылки в files.

На данный момент не работает. Доступ к секции "files" возможен лишь при авторизации как доверенное приложение, либо парсингом страницы https://vk.com/dev/video.get

Answer (score 1):

смотри, вот такой запрос:

> https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?v=5.12&videos=71057340_167884774_6e2f5cee5c04b2b898&access_token=myaccesstoken

получаю такой ответ:

```
{
    response =     {
        count = 1;
        items =         (
                        {
                comments = 4;
                date = 1395082963;
                description = "::::::\U0418\U041d\U0424\U041e\U0420\U041c\U0410\U0426\U0418\U041e\U041d\U041d\U0410\U042f \U0412\U041e\U0419\U041d\U0410:::::::\n:::::http://vkontakte.ru/club4121067:::::";
                duration = 64;
                id = 167884774;
                "owner_id" = 71057340;
                "photo_130" = "http://cs540303.vk.me/u12911501/video/s_f1c9b9d6.jpg";
                "photo_320" = "http://cs540303.vk.me/u12911501/video/l_074712cb.jpg";
                player = "http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=71057340&id=167884774&hash=32fa35ec6b845a99";
                title = "\U041e\U0442\U0434\U044b\U0445 \U0432 \U041a\U0440\U044b\U043c\U0443 - 2014 \U0423\U043a\U0440\U0430\U0438\U043d\U0430. ";
                views = 707;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Обычно ВК не отдает прямой ссылки на видео, хотя иногда есть исключения (они в словаре files должны быть). В таком случае приходиться пользоваться ссылкой на плеер и открывать ее в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в owner_id видео. Параметр owner_id можно взять из данных newsfeed.get. То есть owner_id видео может отличаться от source_id поста, которому принадлежит видео, так как может быть перепост видео другой группой или пользователем.