# Получить не информации о видео, а само видео

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Изначально вопрос такой: "Возможно ли с помощью vk api скачать видео?"

Максимум, который я смог получить, это с помощью метода `video.get` получил информацию о видео.
Мне пришел словарь, в котором были такие ключи: `width`, `height`, `id`, `player` и еще штук 20.
`player` это ссылка на видео (если скачать то, что там (с помощью `requests`), то получишь `html` код, в котором не будет mp4), если туда перейти вручную, то можно найти ссылку на видео.

Если залезть туда с помощью библиотеки `requests`, то ссылки не найти (хедерсов нет, куки нет). Какие хедерссы туда нужны не понятно (если знаете ответ, его тоже напишите). Но это все отвлечение от темы, апи позволило получить ссылку на видео, но возможности скачать не дало. Как без танцев с бубном его скачать.

P.S. у меня получился очень интересный танец, а именно с помощью `webbrowser.open` открываю ссылку, библиотекой `pyautogui` открываю исходный код, ей же копирую, парсю `mp4`, получаю уже ссылку на `mp4` далее это уже иногда получается скачать(иногда качает по 2 байта, иногда полностью это я уже описал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1236357/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BA))

Comment: хедеры вы можете посмотреть с помощью окна разработчика, в хроме это F12, вкладка Network. там же можете уточнить типа запроса - Post/Get

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить видео VKontakte Api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/288901/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-vkontakte-api)